# Is it possible to make "Alphabetical scroll bar - alike" for search?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, alphabetical

Currently I have a view like new feed of facebook where post by users listed in time order. Now on the right hand side I want to put the Alphabetical scroll bar and when user scroll to any character, they can search post by users with name start by that character, is it possible though ?

For my understanding, it could be solve if I can capture the event when user scroll to each character and transfer that character to API on server to query the DB with names start with that and post it back to display on device.

Could any one give me some hint please !

Comment: You should be searching for "UITableView section index". The index you are talking about is part of iOS and fairly straight forward to implement. It has been answered several times on Stack Overflow.

Comment: By using your method, I think normally the view already need to be ordered in alphabetical order, the scrolling only help to quickly jump to each section. While my question is about the list ordered by date time, and when scroll it reorder by alphabet.

Comment: ah I see. Are you not worried that you are breaking a fundamental behaviour of iOS by doing that? If a user sees an alphabetical list down the right hand side of the screen they have been taught (by over 8 years of experience) that that is a quick way to scroll through the list. By changing that in the way you are proposing you will make your app appear to be broken and put off users from using it.

Comment: I never feel that is something to be worried as long as it is convenient to user. Or I can put it to the left hand side to make it different! But let's talk about that later, at first I want to discuss is it possible and how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do is a quite unusual type of user interface, but if you really want to do this, you could do the following (you can find a tutorial [here](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-index-list-uitableview/)):
In your `tableViewController`, create an index array, e.g. an array of alphabetic characters that you want to be displayed at the side of your `tableView`, e.g.:

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    NSARRAY *characters = @[@" ", "A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H", @"I", @"J", @"K", @"L", @"M", @"N", @"O", @"P", @"Q", @"R", @"S", @"T", @"U", @"V", @"W", @"X", @"Y", @"Z"];  
    return characters;
}
```

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:): „*An array of strings that serve as the title of sections in the table view and appear in the index list on the right side of the table view. The table view must be in the plain style (`UITableViewStylePlain`). For example, for an alphabetized list, you could return an array containing strings “A” through “Z”.*“

It is completely up to you, how you sort your data into the sections of the `tableView`. In your case, you want to have all time sorted data in one section, probably without a special header. Therefore your array `characters` starts with a header `@" "` at index 0, and you put all of your time sorted entries in section 0.
Then, implement the following method:

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
              sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title 
              atIndex:(NSInteger)tappedIndex {
     self.savedTappedIndex = tappedIndex;
     return 0;
 }
```

This method may be a bit confusing. It does the following: When the user taps at the index on the side of your `tableView` (`@" " … @"Z"`) a certain character in the array `characters`, the position of this character in the array (its index) is input to this method. You can store it in a property. If you return 0 like in the example, section 0 of the table would be redisplayed as it is.
If you do key value observation ([KVO](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html)) of the property `savedTappedIndex`, you will get a notification when the table is redisplayed.  You can then read the tapped character by

```
NSString *tappedCharacter = characters[self.savedTappedIndex];
```

With this character, you can question your server for feeds, which were created by users whose name starts with this character.
The data can then be displayed in the `tableView`, again in section 0.
Of course, you should then no longer display the index at the side of the `tableView`.

Once again, this behavior may be very confusing to the user, since it is quite unusual.

Final note:

You should not use the hack above for a real implementation, but you could use it to test your user interface, and you will probably see that the user experience is not good, since the index behaves differently as usual.

Comment: Thanks Reinhard for great answer ! It's great that sometime we can think and execute the idea differently ! Best !